# Scale fabric.js canvas objects

Tags: javascript, canvas, meteor, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have a fabric.js canvas on my page, that I'd like to be responsive. My code works for scaling the canvas itself, but not the objects I've drawn on it. Any idea? I've searched SO but couldn't find a solution that worked for me.

```
var resizeCanvas;

resizeCanvas = function() {
  var height, ratio, width;
  ratio = 800 / 1177;
  width = tmpl.$('.canvas-wrapper').width();
  height = width / ratio;

  canvas.setDimensions({
    width: width,
    height: height
  });
};

Meteor.setTimeout(function() {
  return resizeCanvas();
}, 100);

$(window).resize(resizeCanvas);
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Here's my zoom function - We zoom the canvas, and then loop over all objects and scale them as well.

Call like `zoomIt(2.2)`

```
function zoomIt(factor) {
canvas.setHeight(canvas.getHeight() * factor);
canvas.setWidth(canvas.getWidth() * factor);
if (canvas.backgroundImage) {
    // Need to scale background images as well
    var bi = canvas.backgroundImage;
    bi.width = bi.width * factor; bi.height = bi.height * factor;
}
var objects = canvas.getObjects();
for (var i in objects) {
    var scaleX = objects[i].scaleX;
    var scaleY = objects[i].scaleY;
    var left = objects[i].left;
    var top = objects[i].top;

    var tempScaleX = scaleX * factor;
    var tempScaleY = scaleY * factor;
    var tempLeft = left * factor;
    var tempTop = top * factor;

    objects[i].scaleX = tempScaleX;
    objects[i].scaleY = tempScaleY;
    objects[i].left = tempLeft;
    objects[i].top = tempTop;

    objects[i].setCoords();
}
canvas.renderAll();
canvas.calcOffset();
}
```

Comment: in this zoom factor is ratio or some thing else ?

Comment: Percentage. In the example, 2.2 would be 220% of original.

Comment: @zimt28 Can you post how you used this function in conjunction with the `resize` event? This function takes a scale factor - how did you get that from the `resize` event?

Comment: @MichaelBates Old code, but it might be enough to get an idea: https://gist.github.com/zimt28/b33229fdb9559b01803c

Comment: @JasonMaggard: if I do scalling 220% then again I do 150% then objects still increasing scalling because objects[i].scaleX it will give 2.2 and based on that scalling is increasing where it should scale with lower value.

Comment: Piyush, this is now supported directly by Fabric.js. You can zoom the canvas using built in APIs. I wouldn't use this if I were you.

Comment: If you were looking at making objects within objects responsive, I just figured it out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58719714/centering-and-scaling-canvas-object-inside-another-canvas-object-by-width-height/

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for a fabric build-in method for scaling (aka zooming) a canvas, check out [setZoom](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#setZoom).