# Resize canvas Objects in fabric on resize to fit canvas new size

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I need to calculate the objects scale to fit new canvas size on resize, I will explain better with pictures, for example we have this case:

[image: canvas objects before applying the resize]

[image: canvas objects after resize]

another example:

[image]
[image]

So the objects needs to be resized proportionally in different screens and resolutions and I don't want to exceed/overflow the canvas size

for example in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidtorroija/5KKQ2/809/) I need to this objects to strech and fit all the free space in the canvas.

```js
var canvas  = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var shadow = {
    color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)',
    blur: 20,    
    offsetX: 10,
    offsetY: 10,
    opacity: 0.6,
    fillShadow: true, 
    strokeShadow: true 
}

 var rect = new fabric.Rect({
        left: 100,
        top: 100,
        fill:  "#FF0000",
        stroke: "#000",
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        strokeWidth: 10, 
        opacity: .8      
    });
    
  var rect1 = new fabric.Rect({
        left: 50,
        top: 100,
        fill:  "#f0ff00",
        stroke: "#000",
        width: 80,
        height: 80,
        strokeWidth: 10, 
        opacity: .8      
    });
   
rect.setShadow(shadow);
canvas.add(rect);
canvas.add(rect1);
```

```css
#c{
  border:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.4/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: doesn't the canvas have a `scale(scaleWidth,scaleHeight)` function? You could scale the canvas that  way, affecting the way things are drawn.

Comment: What you could do is figure out the ratio of how large the change is `scale(newWidth/oldWidth,newHeight/oldHeight);` might work.

Comment: I just realized you were using fabricjs which i know nothing about, so here is a link that might help you out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28301286/scale-fabric-js-canvas-objects

Comment: yes but I also need to fit all the canvas size in all resolutions(responsive), and thanks I already check that question and did not help me

Comment: Try this: `scale((oldCanvasWidth/oldDrawingWidth) * newCanvasWidth,(oldCanvasHeight/oldDrawingHeight) * newCanvasHeight);`

Comment: You don't need my code man, this is a mathematical problem, but if you want code, here you have http://jsfiddle.net/davidtorroija/5KKQ2/809/

Comment: @Infer-on you put me the -1? please revert that I put the code now