# CSS & Fabric js: Scale canvas and objects on small resolutions

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, fabricjs

I am working with fabricjs for an application. On mobile I need to scale the whole canvas down so it can fit the screen.

The issue is that on the canvas there are 10 objects in total, between images, texts and fabric js `background` objects.

I tried scaling the whole canvas using CSS `transform` and it seems to work, but the whole area gets smaller, as in this picture [image]

The original canvas is the entire picture, but when I apply the `transform`, the canvas becomes the red area, and when moving objects with fabricjs, they get clipped when outside the red area.

Is there any way to fix this in CSS ?
**edit**
Basically I need to scale everything inside the canvas, but the canvas itself needs to always be 100% in height and with of the current window.

Or is there any way to resize the whole canvas with all the objects ? I also tried fabric js `setZoom()` method, but it gets even more messed up.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The best way is find a scale ratio that fit your screen (is unclear how you plan to fit a square canvas on a long screen).

Then leave the css untrasformed. `ratio` is the scale ratio that fit the canvas in screen;

resize the canvas to actual screen dimensions:

```
canvas.setDimensions({ width: originalWidth * ratio, height: originalHeight * ratio });
canvas.setZoom(ratio)
```

This should give you a smaller canvas with everything in place.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, it kinda works but the objects on the canvas are shifted. Initially I set the x,y,width and height of every object so they are centered, but after applying the zoom they all shift to the left, do you know how to solve this or why they shift ? Thank you again

Comment: attach at least a screenshot of this shifting.

Comment: After trying the setDimensions() method, I confirmed that this approach does scale the canvas, but does not appear to scale the objects within the Fabric canvas. For example, placed rectangles are not scaled and are not shifted based on the modified dimensions.

Comment: Hi @A-Diddy I hope you found the solution to this problem. The same thing is happening with my canvas.

Comment: What if I want to implement a zoom in/out feature, like not just within the canvas but the canvas as a whole i.e attach an event listener onto the canvas container for mouse wheel. In this scenario, I'm updating the canvas css everytime on scroll, but now the whole thing kind of breaks, like lines drawn appear in random positions etc. Any thought on how to do this ?

Comment: If you zoom the canvas with CSS then you just get more blurred pixels. Can you be more specific on what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Possible Duplicate: [Scale fabric.js canvas objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28301286/3858863)

It seems Fabric.js doesn't support this natively... at least, I haven't found the options to do it.

Until Fabric.js provides this, the best way may be to iterate through the objects and scale them manually to match the new screen size based on the ratio of the previous screen size. For example...

```
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas({});
let prevScreenWidth = window.innerWidth;
let prevScreenHeight = window.innerHeight;

window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize());

/*********************************************************
 * Get the new screen size ratio in relation to the previous screen size
 * to determine the scale factor.
 *********************************************************/
function handleResize() {
  // Error Handling: Make sure the scale ratio denominator is defined.
  prevScreenWidth = prevScreenWidth || window.innerWidth;
  prevScreenHeight = prevScreenHeight || window.innerHeight;

  // Get the current/new screen width and height (scale ratio numerator).
  const currScreenWidth = window.innerWidth;
  const currScreenHeight = window.innerHeight;

  // Determine width and height scale ratios
  const widthRatio = currScreenWidth / prevScreenWidth;
  const heightRatio = currScreenHeight / prevScreenHidth;

  // Get the average of the width and height scale ratios
  const scaleFactor = (widthRatio + heightRatio) / 2;

  // Scale the objects with the screen size adjustment ratio average as the scale factor 
  scaleObjects(scaleFactor);

  // Record the current screen sizes to be used for the next resize.
  prevScreenWidth = window.innerWidth;
  prevScreenHeight = window.innerHeight;
}


/*********************************************************
 * Iterate through each object and apply the same scale factor to each one.
 *********************************************************/
function scaleObjects(factor) {
  // Set canvas dimensions (this could be skipped if canvas resizes based on CSS).
  canvas.setDimensions({
    width: canvas.getWidth() * factor, 
    height: canvas.getHeight() * factor 
  });

  if (canvas.backgroundImage) {
    // Need to scale background images as well
    const bi = canvas.backgroundImage;
    bi.width = bi.width * factor; bi.height = bi.height * factor;
  }

  const objects = canvas.getObjects();

  for (let i in objects) {
    const scaleX = objects[i].scaleX;
    const scaleY = objects[i].scaleY;
    const left = objects[i].left;
    const top = objects[i].top;

    const tempScaleX = scaleX * factor;
    const tempScaleY = scaleY * factor;
    const tempLeft = left * factor;
    const tempTop = top * factor;

    objects[i].scaleX = tempScaleX;
    objects[i].scaleY = tempScaleY;
    objects[i].left = tempLeft;
    objects[i].top = tempTop;

    objects[i].setCoords();
  }
  canvas.renderAll();
  canvas.calcOffset();
}
```

See this previous answer for more information on the scaleObjects() method... [Scale fabric.js canvas objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28301981/3858863)